# ActiveRecord find records from association with no associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple `many-to-many` relation between two models and a join table. In my Rails controller, I have an ActiveRecord::Relation object called `job_descriptions` which is initialized as `JobDescription.all` and then passed through flow controls to apply additional `where` statements. Here are my models:

```
class JobDescription < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :job_description_experience_levels
    has_many :experience_levels, through: :job_description_experience_levels
end

class JobDescriptionExperienceLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job_description
    belongs_to :experience_level
end

class ExperienceLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :job_description_experience_levels
    has_many :job_descriptions, through: :job_description_experience_levels
end
```

I'm trying to write a query for `job_descriptions` to select only those instances that do not have an `experience_level` association. How can I do this?

I've tried variations of `ob_descriptions.includes(:job_descriptions).where(job_description_experience_levels: {job_description_id: nil})` and `job_descriptions.where('id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(job_description_id) FROM job_description_experience_levels)')` but without success.

Most of the resoures I've been able to find on this subject work by calling a query on the model itself (e.g. `JobDescription.where(something)`) rather than on an existing relation object.

Thanks!

**Edit #1**

I managed to solve this on my own before madyrockss answer, but I think that answer is more semantic than my solution. Here is my solution anyways in case it helps someone down the line.

```
job_descriptions_with_experience_levels = job_descriptions.joins(:experience_levels)
job_descriptions = job_descriptions - job_descriptions_with_experience_levels
```

It works by finding all the `job_descriptions` with `experience_levels` and then subtracting that relation from `job_descriptions` to get the ones without any `experience_levels`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `job_description` do not have any `experience_level` there will be no entry present for that `job_description` in `job_description_experience_levels` table.
So you can do something like following :

```
job_desc_ids_with_exp_level = JobDescriptionExperienceLevel.pluck(:job_description_id).uniq

job_descriptions = job_descriptions.where.not(id: job_desc_ids_with_exp_level)
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to solve it before I saw your answer, but your answer seems more semantic than my solution, which I'll share in my question. Your answer works for selecting the `job_descriptions` that have no `experience_level`, but I modified the second line to call `where` on `job_descriptions` instead of on `JobDescription`.